# Make a sound play when a long-press is hapening

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i am using this script to detect if the mouse pressed an element (link what has image inside) for a longer period of time (more than just a tap):

https://jsfiddle.net/gianlucaguarini/56Szw/

I am trying to modify this script to make it play sound using this script that works separately:
JS:

```
function PlaySound() {
          var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
          sound.play()
      }
```

HTML

```
<audio id="audio" src="sound.mp3" autostart="false" ></audio>
    <a onclick="PlaySound()"> Play</a>
```

But things are not working for me, here is my code:

HTML:

```
    <div id="touchArea">
<audio id="audio" src="sound.mp3" autostart="false" ></audio>
    <a onclick="PlaySound()"> Play</a>
 </div>
```

JS:

```
var getPointerEvent = function(event) {
    return event.originalEvent.targetTouches ? event.originalEvent.targetTouches[0] : event;
};
var jQuerytouchArea = jQuery('#touchArea'),
    touchStarted = false, // detect if a touch event is sarted
    currX = 0,
    currY = 0,
    cachedX = 0,
    cachedY = 0;
//setting the events listeners
jQuerytouchArea.on('touchstart mousedown',function (e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var pointer = getPointerEvent(e);
    // caching the current x
    cachedX = currX = pointer.pageX;
    // caching the current y
    cachedY = currY = pointer.pageY;
    // a touch event is detected      
    touchStarted = true;
    jQuerytouchArea.text('Touchstarted');
    // detecting if after 200ms the finger is still in the same position
    setTimeout(function (){
        if ((cachedX === currX) && !touchStarted && (cachedY === currY)) {
            // Here you get the Tap event
            jQuerytouchArea.text('Tap');
        }
    },200);
});
jQuerytouchArea.on('touchend mouseup touchcancel',function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // here we can consider finished the touch event
    touchStarted = false;
    jQuerytouchArea.text('Touchended');
});
jQuerytouchArea.on('touchmove mousemove',function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var pointer = getPointerEvent(e);
    currX = pointer.pageX;
    currY = pointer.pageY;
    if(touchStarted) {
// here is what should happen when the button is pressed for a long time
function PlaySound() {
      var sound = document.getElementById("audio");
      sound.play()
  }  
    }
});
```